# "No matching function for call" for a class template that inherits from vector

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance

I am trying to make a class template called `Matrix` that inherits from another class template `Sortable` (which inherits from `std::vector<T>`).

`Sortable` is intended to add a sorting function that would belong to an instantiated vector. I am creating a `Matrix` from this with `Sortable<Sortable<int>>` that I will eventually need to sort and do other fun stuff with.

My problem right now is that in my Matrix constructor, I want to initialize the `Sortable<Sortable<int>>` to the given dimensions (rows and columns) but I can't get my code to compile.

When I try to resize my `Sortable<Sortable<int>>` in my `Matrix.h` constructor, I do it like this:

```cpp
m.resize(row, Sortable<T>(col));
```

But when I do, I receive this error:

> no matching function for call to 'Sortable::Sortable(int&)'gcc

This is annoying because I know I can resize a vector just fine with this syntax:

```cpp
v.resize(row, std::vector<int>(col));
```

I'm not sure why the `Sortable` won't play nice.

Note: the `Sortable.h` is not mine, it is given to me and I have made no modifications, and I believe I am not supposed to touch it.

Edit: Thanks @Stephen Newell, the response helped me realize that I was approaching this the wrong way (since it means I have to modify `Sortable.h` to achieve my desired result).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.h"

int main()
{    
    int row, column;
    int val;

    row = 3;
    column = 4;

    Matrix<int> m1(row, column);
}
```

```cpp
// Sortable.h

#include <cstring>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::size_t;

template<class T>
class Sortable : public std::vector<T> {
public:
    void sort();
};

template<class T>
void Sortable<T>::sort() { // A simple sort
    for(size_t i = this->size(); i > 0; --i)
        for(size_t j = 1; j < i; ++j)
            if(this->at(j-1) > this->at(j)) {
                T t = this->at(j-1);
                this->at(j-1) = this->at(j);
                this->at(j) = t;
            }
}

// Partial specialization for pointers:
template<class T>
class Sortable<T*> : public std::vector<T*> {
public:
    void sort();
};

template<class T>
void Sortable<T*>::sort() {
    for(size_t i = this->size(); i > 0; --i)
        for(size_t j = 1; j < i; ++j)
            if(*this->at(j-1) > *this->at(j)) {
                T* t = this->at(j-1);
                this->at(j-1) = this->at(j);
                this->at(j) = t;
            }
}

// Full specialization for char*
// (Made inline here for convenience -- normally you would
// place the function body in a separate file and only
// leave the declaration here).
template<> inline void Sortable<char*>::sort() {
    for(size_t i = this->size(); i > 0; --i)
        for(size_t j = 1; j < i; ++j)
            if(std::strcmp(this->at(j-1), this->at(j)) > 0) {
                char* t = this->at(j-1);
                this->at(j-1) = this->at(j);
                this->at(j) = t;
            }
}
```

```cpp
// Matrix.h

#include "Sortable.h"

template<class T>
class Matrix : public Sortable<T>
{
public:
    Sortable<Sortable<T>> m;

    Matrix(int row, int col)
    {
        m.resize(row, Sortable<T>(col));
    }
};
```

Comment: You haven't declared a constructor for `Sortable`.

Comment: Yeah seeing your comment makes that pretty clear to me now... is there no way to leverage vector's constructor here?

Comment: Yes, `using std::vector<T>::vector;` inside of `Sortable`. But inheriting from a vector just to add a simple method is probably not the best idea. Also `Matrix` has two vectors in it, one `m` and the other inherited - probably wasn't intended.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that, I just tried it for myself! I made `m` so that I had a handle on the vector, but I see now that I can use it directly like a vector. How would I reference that vector from within the header file though?